# How to configure dynamic "input" results in Struts2

Tags: struts2, struts-validation

Suppose I configure a "per method" validation into my action, using the Struts2 validation framework (in my example with annotations, but also with xml it is the same).
Suppose I have three public exposed methods in my action:

```java
public class MyAction extends ActionSupport {

    @Override
    public String execute() throws Exception {

        //some code here...
    }

    @Validations(
        customValidators = {@CustomValidator(type="myCostomValidator", fieldName="myFieldName", shortCircuit=true, message="")}         
    )
    public String info() {

        //some code here...
    }

    @Validations(
        customValidators = {@CustomValidator(type="myCostomValidator", fieldName="anotherFieldName", shortCircuit=true, message="")},
        visitorFields = {@VisitorFieldValidator(context="update_context", fieldName="anObjectField", message="", shortCircuit=true)}            
    )
    public String update() {

        //some code here...
    }

    //getters, setters and other...
}
```

Now, each of the three methods can be invoked and has a different validation. If the validation fails the framework set the result "input" that must be configured into the struts.xml:

```xml
<action name="myAction_*" method="{1}" class="com.test.gui.action.test.MyAction">
    <result name="success">result1.jsp</result>
    <result name="edit">result2.jsp</result>
    <result name="input">result3.jsp</result>
</action>
```

How can I have different "input" results for each action method? For example, I'd like to reach one page if the validation fails for the info() method and another page if the validation fails for the update() method.
Thank you.

Comment: Results can take an OGNL expression, but... as-is this would tie the Java side directly to the presentation layer. My first thought would be to see if the default workflow interceptor could be configured via OGNL to return a different result name other than `"input"`, but I'm not sure if that would be evaluated properly--but I'd still try it to see what happens.

Comment: I would split it in three actions, eventually sharing a base-action with common stuff (prepare() or something). Then each one can return its own INPUT result. More action methods in a single action class has sense if the methods shares almost everything, but if even the common results must be different, then it would be better to use different actions with a single method each one, IMHO

Answer (score 2):

I've found this solution: the use of `@InputConfig` annotation.

With this annotation you can set a 'per method' result name for validation errors. So in the struts.xml you can configure for each result name the page that you want to reach.

Examples:

```
@InputConfig(resultName="input_update")
public String update() {
    // perform action
    return SUCCESS;
}
```

and in struts.xml: `<result name="input_update">jsp/input_update.jsp</result>`

or:

```
@InputConfig(methodName="inputMethod")
public String update() {
    // perform action
    return SUCCESS;
}
public String inputMethod() {
    // perform some data filling
    return INPUT;
}
```

struts.xml: `<result name="input">jsp/myInput.jsp</result>`

See documentation at [struts.apache.org/docs/inputconfig-annotation.html](https://struts.apache.org/docs/inputconfig-annotation.html)

It can also be set the input result name in the struts.xml by setting a parameter for the 'workflow' interceptor, but it affects all methods in the action:

```
<interceptor-ref name="workflow">
    <param name="inputResultName">custom_input_result</param>
</interceptor-ref>
```

see doc here [struts.apache.org/docs/default-workflow-interceptor.html](https://struts.apache.org/docs/default-workflow-interceptor.html)

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to modify returned result name. You are using wildcard mapping for your action, so use it for JSP file name as well.

```xml
<action name="myAction_*" method="{1}" class="com.test.gui.action.test.MyAction">
    <result name="success">success.jsp</result>
    <result name="input">result_{1}.jsp</result>
</action>
```

Comment: It works! But it is a bit limiting because in this case it is not possible to make sure that two different methods on an action have the same result page for "input". For example, suppose I have three methods on the same action: search(), create(), update() and that, in case of validation errors, I want that search() ends on test_search.jsp and that create() and update() each one end in the same page, for example test_edit.jsp. How can I configure the struts.xml?

Comment: @Perelum: The simplest way would be to create two pages and include your edit form.